# Where to put setInterval() in order to print out new quote every hour?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript so please don't crucify me. Anyways, I have a clickHandler() method here:

```
function clickHandler() {
 var promise = fetch('https://jokes-plaul.rhcloud.com/api/joke');
 promise.then(function (response) {
   return response.json();
 }).then(function (quote) {
   document.getElementById("joke").innerHTML = quote.joke;

 });
```

My question is: where exactly should I put setInterval() in order for my code to update a quote every hour? I'd rather if someone explained it than gave me an answer straight away, thank you kind people!

Comment: Do you need the click event at all ? if not, then set the `setInterval` out of click event. You can definitely use click event to `clearInterval` or reset the interval duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval receives two parameters, function and integer representing interval.

So, in your case you can do that after your function defenition:

```
setInterval(clickHandler, 1000*60*60)
```

Just make sure that you don't call your function by using curly braces:

```
//INCORRECT
setInterval(clickHandler(), 1000*60*60)
```

Best source to read about that more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval